# Mysql query results around some ID

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have table like this:

```
id: PRIMARY INT
price: INT (in dollars)
typeOfHouse: TINYINT (enumerated house types)
```

and there exists tuple, let's say  (id=3, price=1243, typeOfHouse=20).

Now I want to select 2 cheaper houses and 2 expensiver ones (2 up, 2 down). That could be done with two queries (UNION):

```
SELECT * FROM houses WHERE typeOfHouse=20 AND price>=1243 ORDER BY price LIMIT 3
SELECT * FROM houses WHERE typeOfHouse=20 AND price<=1243 ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 3
```

This is a hypothetical example, the condition will in general be much more complex, so the question is - **is it possible to do that faster in one query**, so **the condition selection doesn't have to be perfomed twice.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is fine. You can combine in one query with `UNION`:

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM houses 
    WHERE typeOfHouse = 20       --- there may be more more houses
      AND price = 1243           --- with same price
UNION ALL
    SELECT * 
    FROM houses 
    WHERE typeOfHouse = 20 
      AND price > 1243 
    ORDER BY price 
    LIMIT 2
UNION ALL
    SELECT * 
    FROM houses 
    WHERE typeOfHouse = 20 
      AND price < 1243 
    ORDER BY price DESC 
    LIMIT 2
```

If there is an index on `price` or - even better - a compound index on `(typeOfHouse, price)`, you don't have to worry about performance.

Comment: From question: This is a hypothetical example, the condition will in general be much more complex, so the question is - is it possible to do that faster in one query, so the condition selection doesn't have to be perfomed twice.

Comment: Althrough you get +1 for effort.

Comment: It depends on the complexity of the condition, the indices you have on the table and the selectivity of the conditions.

Comment: How many rows does `SELECT * FROM houses WHERE (complex condition)` return? When you have no limitation on price?

Comment: Sometimes only few, sometimes whole table. It really is very dynamic, depending on external filters. I was hoping there exists some magical trick, but apparently there doesn't :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `BETWEEN` operator, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM houses WHERE typeOfHouse=20 AND price BETWEEN 1241 AND 1245 ORDER BY price
```

Comment: And if the house prices are (in this order) 1235, 1239, 1243, 1244, 1247?

Comment: The prices are in dollars. They are not ranks or something like this.